# MetaMask Mobile SDK - App crashes shortly after opening

Tags: metamask

I've been working with the MetaMask Mobile SDK and followed the instructions outlined in the README (link to the README here: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile) to generate an APK. However, I'm facing an issue where the app crashes after 1 or 2 seconds of being opened.

I've gone through the steps carefully and double-checked my implementation, but I can't seem to pinpoint the cause of the crash.

Additionally, I'm curious to know if others have successfully generated an APK from this GitHub repository. If so, could you please share any insights or additional steps that might be necessary for a successful build?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Thanks in advance for your help!

I've gone through the steps carefully and double-checked my implementation, but I can't seem to pinpoint the cause of the crash.